# How can I access SQL Server LocalDB in the SQL Server Import and Export wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssms, localdb

I have a SQL Server LocalDB and can connect and access it from an ASP.NET application, via connection string and this code:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(conString);
});
```

I can also connect to this localdb with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

But I cannot connect to it in the Import & Export Wizard. Which "Destination" should I choose there? "SQL Server Native Client" or ".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" or something else?

My connection string that works is from the .net App is:
"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SBot1070"

The "Server Name" property in the working SSMS connection is "(localdb)"

Comment: I'd try the "SQL Server Native Client" - after all, LocalDB **IS** SQL Server (a special version of SQL Server Express)

Comment: Thats where I see the best chance, but I do not get it going. WHen asked for servername I tried many things like "(localdb)" or "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB" always Windows Authentication. Any hint how to access?

Comment: Well - how do you access it in SSMS ? Use the same "server/instance" combination that works there. Also: LocalDB must be started up to be accessed by your wizard - have you done that? It's not running by default, at all times (that exactly it's "selling point" - it's not running at all times, using system resources). Use the `sqllocaldb` tool

Comment: it is running, i can use it from the .net application, i can do everything on the database from SSMS. What exactly should I use for "server/instance"? "localhost/MSSQLLocalDB" for instance does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That worked:
SQL Server Native Client
(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

[image]